# Linux C: Reference to non-static member function must be called

Tags: c++, linux

I receive `error:Reference to non-static member function must be called` trying to build the following code:

```
HTTPClient::HTTPClient(int id,HttpListener& message) {
    pthread_t thId;
    pthread_create(&thId, NULL, processor, this);  <--error is here
}

void* HTTPClient::processor(void* userData) {
    HTTPClient* client = static_cast<HTTPClient*>(userData);
    client->run();
}

void HTTPClient::run() {
    while(true) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mMutex);
        pthread_cond_wait(&mCond,&mMutex);
        httpLoadFile(mUrl, mPath);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mMutex);
    }
}
```

I have found some methods trying to solve the error, but failed!

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: pthreads is a C library, so it doesn't deal all too well with C++ member functions but you can use a simple lambda as a workaround `pthread_create(&thId, NULL, [this](void* arg){return this->processor(arg);},this); ` Although passing `this` seems somewhat silly if it's already captured in the lambda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says you cannot pass pointer to method into `pthread_create`, you should pass pointer to ordinary function.